# Getting nth item of array created by performing .split() in ColdFusion 8

Tags: javascript, string, coldfusion

Okay, I get that performing the following will create an array of my string split on the `_`:

```
<cfset theString = "get_the_point">
<cfset thePieces = theString.Split("_{1}")>
```

But, how do I get just the 3rd item in the array without having to create a new variable that evaluates the array like:

```
<cfset theThirdPiece = thePieces[3]>
```

Is there something to the `.Split()` that I don't know about that can return just the specific item I'm looking for? This has to be super easy because I didn't find anything in the documentation. Or I was searching it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a simple delimiter like the underscore, you can do:

```
<cfset thePiece = listGetAt("get_the_point", 3, "_")>
```

All list functions take an optional delimiter argument that is a list of single characters to use as delimiters.

Remember to check the listLen() of the list before attempting to access the nth location.

Comment: Ben, thank you. So, essentially no, you can't use the `.split()` method to get just the one thing other than the array. This seems to be a nice elegant way to handle my problem within my cfc.

Comment: technically speaking, the .split() method is an undocumented feature.  because ColdFusion strings are essentially Java strings, you get that method, but its not a true, documented ColdFusion feature.

Comment: @Sean Coyne: sorry to pick on you, but ColdFusion to Java data types  *are* documented: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Java_8.html

Comment: that page lists how they translate back and forth when calling Java functions. So if I load a Java library, for example, I know that I don't have to JavaCast a ColdFusion string to a Java string, because ColdFusion will do it for me. The same will happen in the reverse direction. A string returned from Java will auto-translate to a CF string. In the future, Adobe could use a different class for a string, which may not have that method, and this code would break. The chances of that are extremely unlikely, and I have used .split() on many occasions, but it should be known that its undocumented.

Comment: @orangepips-Despite my thinking it is unlikely the conversions will change (for several reasons), that one-pager never gives me warm fuzzy feelings of confidence. Logically I can reach certain conclusions. But when it comes to the topic of supported/unsupported, I would rather not resort inference.  If certain *internal implementations* are fully supported (future versions, backward compatibility, tech-support, etc.) then the documentation should say so _explicitly_ and list supported items in detail. For all I know they may be supported now. But that is not clearly stated in the documentation

Comment: split() is a bad example - but a good practice for using undocumented methods is to encapsulate them into a UDF.  That way if things ever did change you'd only need to 'fix' it in one place.

Comment: One consideration that is usually not mentioned is compatibility. The internal stuff is not as cross-compatible as the documented tags/functions. So code relying on the internal voodoo is not as portable. Not an issue for everyone. But good to keep in mind.

Comment: @Todd - btw: agreed on encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the whole picture I would propose a bit simpler/cleaner way to do what you need -- if you need the `last` item:

```
<cfset thePiece = ListLast("get_the_point", "_") />
```

BTW, looking into the Java-related discussion in the comments of accepter answer I would note that there's a native function for splitting:

```
<cfset theString = "get_the_point" />
<cfset thePieces = ListToArray(theString, "_") />
```

I suppose it uses the same `Split` under the hood.

Comment: Here's an interesting (but somewhat old) post from Ben Nadel about the dangers of using the split() method because it doesn't create a ColdFusion array. I came across while researching an answer. So, it's evidently different under the hood... http://www.bennadel.com/blog/492-Caution-Java-String-Split-Does-Not-Create-A-ColdFusion-Array.htm

Comment: When you start using the java stuff you will find there are a lot of subtle differences from CF that can trip you up.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify that it is syntactically correct I should point out that you could also do this:

```
<cfset lastOne = theString.Split("_")[3] />
```

I *believe* this only works in CF9+

Comment: Indeed, in my test CF8 throws an error "Invalid CFML Construct..." when it sees the first `[` in the code.